# How to add, in Entity Framework, entities that differs only by Id (but let In management to EF)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I would like to know the best practices for the insertion of items in EF when items only differs by Id (the Id field is an int which is the key of the corresponding table).

For now, I let the Id to null, then EF produces the correct Id based on the last Id in database, I guess.

But since I have to enter many records, sometimes I have to add 2 records with the same data (except the Id). If I don't want to manage the Ids by myself, What can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Just write an sql query, it's not so difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too broad and general. Just check any batch processing in EF.

Generally speaking, is not worth to reuse objects just because they share some similar data, you should create as many objects as you want, add them to the list and save the context.

If there are many objects to insert, the first step would be to optimize the insert:

- Call `SaveChanges` each X items, so EF send some, but not all to the same time.
- If you do not need the ids, use the context with no tracking.
- etc.

If you have a lot more objects and this does not work for you, you can use an external tool like [EF Extensions](https://entityframework-extensions.net/), that has a bulk insert utility

```
// Easy to use
context.BulkInsert(customers);

// Easy to customize
context.BulkInsert(invoices, options => options.IncludeGraph = true);
```

If you have even more objects, or your server memory is really, really, really restrained, then yes, you can use the same object, but you have to set the id to 0 and detach the object each time is created.

```
dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
```